# How to get particularly selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here I have dynamic dropdowns based on provider. I have two providers example providerid=15 and providerid=16. Whenever I am selecting dropdown of providerid=15 I am getting selected dropdown value of that one but whenever I am selecting dropdown of providerid=16 I am getting static option which I kept i.e.,"Avaliability" is coming. I dont want that static value I want providerid=16 dropdwon selected value.

This is my code:

```
@if (provider.lstSession.Count > 0)
   {
      <div class="form-group" id="svcn">
          <div style="color:red">  @ViewBag.Message</div>
           <select id="SessionID" name="SessionID" class="form-control">
            <option>Avaliablity</option>
             @foreach (var Sesssion in provider.lstSession)
              {
                 if (provider.ProviderID == Sesssion.ProviderID)
                  {
                   <option value="@Sesssion.ProviderID'_'@Sesssion.SessionID" id="sss">@Sesssion.SessionName</option>
                   }
              }
           </select>
          </div>
     }

 $("#SessionID").change(function (){
 var slotvalue = $('#SessionID :selected').val();
       });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about. Please show us the rendered HTML, because you're likely not writing the `<option>` for the provider id you think you are selecting. Note that IDs must be unique to the document, so that `id="sss"` will violate that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Will

```
$(this).val()
```

not work? Also inspect the drop down via Dev tools, try to get a jsfiddle created with generated html and no server side code for others to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "this" to get the actual selected value, not the first one selected:

```js
 $("#SessionID").change(function (){
  var slotvalue = $('#SessionID :selected', this).val();
 });
```

or

```js
 $("#SessionID").change(function (){
  var slotvalue =  $(this).find('option:selected').val();
 });
```

Comment: both are not working working for the second dropdown i.e., for providerid=16